Sorting the string combined with arrayformula()
I have this data in Col A and the result I want in col B :

I want to create arrayformula in col B so it will take the string from col A and sort it.
if without using arrayformula() then per row I can use this formula (for example in col B1) :
=join(",",sort(tocol(split(A1,","))))

My question how to combine it with the arrayformula() to automatically apply for every value in col A. I tried this one but doesn't work :
=ARRAYFORMULA( join(",",sort(tocol(split(A1:A,",")))) )


Use MAP() or BYROW() function. Try-
=MAP(TOCOL(A:A,1),LAMBDA(r,JOIN(",",SORT(TOCOL(SPLIT(r,","),1)))))


